# Opened blender file, lost objects new to blender

Tags: objects

[image]

Hello all, I opened the blender file I was working on and it opened to the enclosed img. I am not sure why or how it opened into this and I am not sure how to return it to normal. Please help

Comment: sidenote even posting on this form with acceptable tags is confusing I have a lot to learn it seems

Comment: Figured it out. ended up hitting esc and everything is fixed

Comment: That file has been saved just after rendering and is showing the UV/image editor, which is set to show the "render result", but the rendered image is not preserved after closing the file. So when you reopen the saved file, it show the last "window setup", but without the previous "render result". If you saved that "render result", you can load it there as a normal image, though.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are in the Image Editor.

Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> or click on this small button a drop down and select 3D View:

[image]